# TFTP times out in CentOS 7

Tags: centos, dhcp, syslinux, tftp, xinetd

I have an isolated server that telnets into the single device on its network and loads a file to it using the telnet command `load`. I am trying to recreate the functionality on another PC. The old computer runs CentOS 6 and the new one I am setting up is running CentOS 7.

```
# tftp -v localhost
> get hello.txt
```

hangs then times out after a minute. There is a file `hello.txt` in `/var/lib/tftpboot`. This `tftpboot` folder is owned by `nobody` and is in group `root`. Its mode bits are set 777.

Likewise, telnetting into the lone device works fine, but the `load` command times out.

So far I have installed these using `#yum install <package-name>`:

```
systemlinux
tftp
dhcp
```

`#ps -e | grep -i ftp` returns nothing.

```
#ps -e | grep -i inet
1241 ?  00:00:00  xinetd
```

`/etc/xinetd.d/tftp` looks like this:

```
service tftp
{
    disable = no
    socket_type = dgram
    protocol = udp
    port = 69
    wait = yes
    user = root
    server = /user/sbin/in.tftpd
    server_args = -vs /var/lib/tftpboot
    per_source = 11
    cps = 100 2
    flags = IPv4
}
```

Because I want any lone device connected to this computer to be assigned a specific IP address, `/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf` assigns one specific IP address:

```
authoritative;
subnet 169.254.0.0 netmask 255.255.0.0 {
    range 169.254.0.100 169.254.0.100;
    max-lease-time 10;
}
```

Note that the DHCP functionality works fine and the lone network device does indeed receive that IP address, and I can telnet into it just fine.

Comment: What about the logs?

Comment: Make sure you have Firewalld set up to allow connections on the tftpd port.

Answer (score 1):

Verify that tftp server is listening on port 69 using '`netstat -an|grep 69`
', if not you may need to reload/restart xinetd daemon to start tftp

PS: Also make sure to use IPv4 address i.e 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost, which could resolve to IPv6